# GroupBox in winform is not accessible in code behind page

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a simple winform application i have a `GroupBox` in designer.cs page which i can also see in design.Now when i try to access the `m_ConstraintGroupBox` from code behind i am not able to access where as there are `ComboBox` `Label` and other controls which i can access.Below in my designer code.

```
 System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox m_ConstraintGroupBox;
 m_ConstraintGroupBox= new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.SuspendLayout();
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.cmbConstriant);
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.lblConstraint);
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(378, 194);
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Name = "m_ConstraintGroupBox";
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(216, 79);
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.TabIndex = 3;
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.TabStop = false;
 m_ConstraintGroupBox.Text = "Constraint";
```

Code for accessing is below

```
public sealed partial class LinkForm : AMBaseForm
{
    private Link m_link;
    private readonly BindingList<Interface> m_interfaces = new BindingList<Interface>();
    private DomainFilterROCollection<ComponentClass> m_availComponentClasses;
    private DomainFilterROCollection<Gauge> m_gaugies;

    public LinkForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cmbConstriant.Visible = false;
                lblConstraint.Visible = false;
                m_ConstraintGroupBox.
        m_ChooseIconControlControl.IsNode = false;

    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to access the GroupBox? BTW: Can you access "groupBox1"?

Comment: Are you trying to access it before calling InitializeComponent?

Comment: I am access after InitializeComponent();

Comment: Can you please post the full code surrounding the snippet you posted. So the above code is in the InitializeComponent()?

Comment: I can access groupBox1